# Prevent tsvncache from running

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I use TortoiseSVN on Windows Xp. But there's a process called tsvncache.exe which always runs in the background and specially locks USB drives.how do I prevent tsvncache from running?
Do I need to disable the entire Tortoise shell extension.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In TortoiseSVN Settings, under Icon Overlays, set your Status cache to
either Shell or None. The dialog looks like this:

[image: Set 'Status cache' to None to terminate the TSVNCache.exe process.]

Good discussion [here](http://tigris-scm.10930.n7.nabble.com/Disable-TSVNCache-exe-to-minimize-disk-IO-td14734.html).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can disable it from running on USB drives, so you still get the advantages of it running on your main drives.

Comment: how do i do that (disable it from running on USB drives)?

Comment: see [this link](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2007/09/26/optimize-tortoise-svn-cache-tsvncache.exe-disk-io.aspx) for info on how to do that